# What is the time complexity for this specific algorithm?

Tags: time-complexity

Given this algorithm:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    sum += i;
```

What is the ordo value? I've solved most of practice exercises but I don't know how to solve this one. Any help very appreciate.

Comment: Hint: how many times will you go through the `for` loop? Generalize that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This algorithm is O(5), that is to say a constant.

Sum all integers in range [0;4] is a constant time whatever the data input.

Answer (score 0):

that algorithm is O(n) linear time complexity

Comment: The “algorithm” does not depend on `n`. Its complexity is in no sensible way O(n).